vectorize an Ax=b solver
A lot of numerical solvers (such as this one), for some reason, only supports solving Ax=b where x, b are vectors.
What if I want to solve AX = B, where X and B are matrices.
I know numerically one should almost never invert a matrix. and there are special reasons I want to use an iterative solver. For example I have a reasonable guess of the solution. I just want to find a way to generalize the Ax=b solver (where x,b are vectors) to AX=B (where X, B are matricies).
I can loop over the vectors, but looping would have overhead, and I dont want to directly use numpy.linalg.solve because I do want to use the special feature of Ax=b solver. Is there a feature in python that speeds this up?

Reading the docs, it looks like the SciPy library already supports a matrix for A and a vector for B. Can you clarify the question and include an error message?

@darthbith I want to solve B as a matrix though?

So A is a 3-D matrix then?

@darthbith, I think he wants the regular 2d A case, but with multiple x vector solutions (effectively in parallel).

@hpaulj Possibly, but there are number of approaches to take, depending on what the OP actually wants, but we don't have a clear answer

There is no inherent reason iterative solvers cannot be extended to handle batched right-hand sides. An immediate question is of course how to define the stopping criterion: different columns of B may need different number of iterations. This is likely one reason why scipy.sparse.linalg solvers only accept a single r.h.s.
That said, these solvers are pure python, so you can rather easily drop them into your code and adapt to your specific problem.

but I want to avoid the python looping overhead?

Taylor, is that python looping overhead killing you?  Often a few (relatively speaking) iterations on a complex task are optimal.  What we try to avoid is many iterations on a simple task. Also check the source code of your task - if available.

Wanting to solve AX=B when all terms are matrices is a red herring: you already have the answer. We can always move terms by left/right multiplying with an inverse leaving us with the form V = W, which doesn't need solving: V is W, we're already done.
If we have AX=B, and we know A and B and need to find X, then we just calculate A⁻¹B:
AX = B, thus
A⁻¹AX = A⁻¹B, thus
X = A⁻¹B, QED

Writing a function for that would probably even be overkill, but if you really wanted to, it's a one-liner (assuming you're already importing matmul and inv since you're working with matrices):
from numpy import matmul
from numpy.linalg import inv

def mat_solve_ax_is_b(A, B):
  return matmul(inv(A), B)

(of course, A needs to be invertible, but if you're working at the level where you're trying to solve Ax=b and AX=B, it feels reasonable to assume you're working with "well behaved" matrices)

numerically one should almost never invert a matrix. and there are special reasons I want to use an iterative solver. For example I have a reasonable guess of the solution

Cool: remember to put all of that in your post because the fewer details you give, the less useful answers you get. Be specific, get good answers.

got it, thanks ...

np.linalg.inv says it does the matrix solve, A X = I. I think the question here is whether any of the scipy.sparse iterative solvers handles matrices.  Maybe not,  since the optimal number of iterations could vary.

why not simply use np.linalg.solve(A, B) instead of reinventing the wheel?

Feel free to post that an answer instead of as a comment question. This answer was from before the OP edited their question with more details.

please bear in mind that regardless of the edit, this solution uses  inv(A) @ B which is exactly  solve(A, B). This idea has nothing to do with the OP's question. Anyway, all these options do not help with OP current line of question, so cannot really post it. Thanks though

I think you can do this way:
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

# Squared error, you may try other objective functions
def func(X, A, B):
    
    return ((B - A @ X.reshape(A.shape[1], -1))**2).sum() # squared error

A = np.random.rand(7, 9)
X = np.random.rand(9, 6)
B = A @ X

X_initial_guess = np.zeros_like(X)  # your initial guess

X_hat = minimize(func, X_initial_guess.flatten(), args=(A, B), method='CG')

X_hat = X_hat.x.reshape(A.shape[1], -1) # recover shape

B_hat = A @ X_hat
np.abs(B - B_hat).sum() # absolute error, I got ~4e-05

Please, note that you may have infinite or no solutions, especially for non-square matrices. Thus, in that cases you will need to compare B matrices instead of X, as shown in the example snippet to see how well you solve it. Since, you have reasonable good guess, it may help to find exact solution you want. If you have square matrices with single solution, than you can directly compare X with X_hat.
To have the best approximate solution in terms of least squares I would recommend to use sklearn's MultiOutputRegressor:
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(7,9)
X = np.random.rand(9,6)
B = A @ X

# Solve AX = B for the best possible approximate solution in terms of least squares
regr = MultiOutputRegressor(LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)).fit(A, B)
X_hat = np.vstack([i.coef_ for i in regr.estimators_]).T

B_hat = A @ X_hat

np.abs(B - B_hat).sum() # absolute error: I got ~3.5e-14

You still need to use loop here to aggregate all the coefficients, but a lot of stuff is done under the hood. Instead of LinearRegression you can also use others, such as Ridge, Lasso or SGDRegressor. For Ridge regressor you can even choose the solver you want, or if you want to utilize stochastic gradient descent, than SGDRegressor should be your choice. Unfortunately, here the APIs don't provide initial guess argument.
Alternatively you can even use Keras or PyTorch. I'll bring the example in Keras:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(7, 9)
X = np.random.rand(9, 6)
B = A @ X

X_initial_guess = np.random.rand(*X.shape) # your initial guess

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=A.shape),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(B.shape[1], use_bias=False, weights=[X_initial_guess])
])

# you can also try other optimizers, like tf.keras.optimizers.SGD
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1), run_eagerly=True)

model.fit(
    x=A.reshape(1, *A.shape),
    y=B.reshape(1, *B.shape),
    epochs=200, # you may need to increase epochs for better fit
    verbose=False,
)

B_hat = A @ model.weights[0].numpy()

np.abs(B - B_hat).sum() # absolute error: I got ~4e-4


Seriously, doing nonlinear least squares for a linear solve is a massive overkill. Plus which, this definitely does not play well with iterative solvers, which the question is about.

@ev-br didn't catch your point. There is no nonlinear least squares in my example, it is linear.

fmin_* are all nonlinear minimizers

@ev-br I think you are mixing the terms. So linear optimization, aka linear programming, is where you have linear objective function, one of the such optimization well known technique is simplex method for example. Here, you cannot use the power of calculus, since everything is linear. To use the power of calculus your objective function should be nonlinear. You can imagine gradient descent algorithm for linear regression problem. Objective function (loss function) is mean squared error, i.e. nonlinear, but you are finding parameters which has linear relationships.

... continuation of previous comment (due to character limitation). Nonlinear least squares is where your have nonlinear relationships among your unknown parameters. As you can see in my 2 examples there is no such cases. But even for nonlinear least squares, you usually calculates nonlinear features, normalize them and again use linear least square as fitting model. For simplicity you can imagine polynomial feature extraction plus linear regression model.

fmin_bfgs is a nonlinear optimizer (not even least squares, sorry)

@ev-br I'm not sure whether you have read or have understood my previous comments. If you wanted to mean, that BFGS is second-order optimization algorithm, than yes, I'm not objecting it, but you can still use it for least squares. You can image the optimization algorithms as your hyperparameters. It might be more suitable to use a method with lower memory requirements, such as Gradient Descent, Conjugate Gradient or L-BFGS. That's why I've put it in comment, but in fact it is faster than Powell here. So, whether BFGS is the best choice depends on the data.

I did. And I stand by my original comment: using general optimization techniques for solving a linear system is a massive overkill. Even if technically possible.

@ev-br The question does not state about the efficiency at all, the main point is to use iterative approach with good guess capability. BFGS is more computationally expensive than each iteration of a first-order method, but it can convergence faster, and compensate the higher cost per iteration, depending on how good your initial guess actually is. As I said I'm not using BFGS in my example, it is just comment. So, what is your point, you want me to remove the comment and use fmin_cg instead? I gave general idea, the rest you can adapt on your own.

@ev-br I've edited the answer, based on your comment. It is now conjugate gradient. What do you think? Any feedback is much appreciated.
